# how to make background 100% on a top menu

Tags: html, css

iam trying to do a top menu with the width of the background color to 100%.
and keep the content of my menu inside my wrap id which 960px.

Can somebody explain me how to do it.

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/NnCVv/246/

html:

```
<div id="wrap">
<ul>
  <li><a href="#">Link 1</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Link 2</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Link 3</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Link 4</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Link 5</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Link 6</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Link 7</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Link 8</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Link 9</a></li>
</ul>
</div>
```

CSS

```
*
{
    padding: 0px;
    margin: 0px;
}

#wrap
{
    width: 960px;
    margin: 0px auto;
    margin: 0px auto;
}

ul
{
    background: navy;
    overflow: hidden;
}

ul li
{
    float: left;
    list-style: none;
}

ul li a
{
    display: block;
    padding: 10px 15px;
    color: white;
    text-decoration: none;
}
```

Comment: There are like trillions of questions like this on S.O - Google this error - fix the server side scripts and it will go away

Comment: Almost all of this issues is about server responded with html instead of js script.

Comment: But you may be just write php code to your js script and not setup the server to preprocess js files as php scripts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>

<html>


<head> 

   <style>
*
{
    padding: 0px;
    margin: 0px;
}
#banner
{
  width:100%;
  background-color:green;
}
#wrap1
{
background-color:black;
    width: 960px;

}

#wrap
{

    margin: 0px auto;
    margin: 0px auto;
}

ul
{
    background: navy;
    overflow: hidden;
}

ul li
{
    float: left;
    list-style: none;
}

ul li a
{
    display: block;
    padding: 10px 15px;
    color: white;
    text-decoration: none;
}

</style>
</head>


<body>
 <div id="banner">
<div id="wrap1">


<ul id="wrap">
  <li><a href="#">Link 1</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Link 2</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Link 3</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Link 4</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Link 5</a></li>

  <li><a href="#">Link 6</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Link 7</a></li>

  <li><a href="#">Link 8</a></li>

</ul>
</div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Is there a way to center "ul", so we can hvae the menu in center of the webpage

Comment: you can use margin-left on id wrap1 in my answer and align as you like.